# Show popup on hover only if i hover on li after 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I'm trying to show inner div on hover on li. I'm doing fadeIn and fadeOut effect but the problem is when I hover quickly on all li fadeIn effect work for all. Where it should show only if I hover on li for 1 second and if I leave that element before one second it shouldn't show fadein effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       var _changeInterval = null;
        $( ".badge_icon" ).hover(function() {
             clearInterval(_changeInterval)

             _changeInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $(this).find(".badges_hover_state").fadeIn(500);
            }, 1000);

        },function() {

             $(this).find('.badges_hover_state').fadeOut(500);

        }); 
      });
</script>
```

I have tried to use stop(), delay() also but didn't get success. At last I tried to do with time interval but now my code has stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this issue by adding window in front of variable name.

```
var myTimeout;

    $('.div').mouseenter(function() {
      window.el = $(this);
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
           el.css("width","200px");
        }, 1000);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        el.css("width","100px");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use this jquery script:

```
var myTimeout;
$('#div').mouseenter(function() {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        //Do stuff
    }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```

See the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4a84mnvL/)

Comment: i have done some changes now now its stop working could you please tell me the problem now https://jsfiddle.net/4a84mnvL/

Comment: you send me the link of my demo... send me your changes

Comment: i added this code to my website. without timeout fadein works bt nt with timeout..